# How to MOSFET to drive 12v relay from microcontroller (logic high is 3.3V) using ZXMS6004FF

Tags: microcontroller, relay, switch-mode-power-supply, mosfet-driver

[image: Schematics]

The above is part of my project design. 'BRAKE_CTL_3' is output pin from uController. It sends 0 or 1 to drive Q4 to turn it on or off. 'BRAKE_LSD_3' connect to one end of Relay. Other end of relay is connected to +12V. I would expect my design to turn relay on or off. However, relay is always turned on(closed). When I measured the pin output at 'BRAKE_LSD_3', the voltage switch from 0 to 3.3V instead of 0V to 12V(ideally). I dont know whats wrong with my design? Can anyone help?

Comment: Ten bucks says the mosfet has too high a VGS for 3.3v. Either add a transistor to control the mosfet and invert logic,  or replace the mosfet.

Comment: @Passerby - The Diodes Inc data sheet says that the ZXMS6004FF will be ON to handle a Drain current of 0.9A with a Vin of 3.0V at 25C as long as the device is mounted on a 15x15mm square of 1 oz copper. You can send be the ten bucks.

Comment: @Passerby Its an "IntelliFET" so it switches sharply at 3V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MOSFET is connected upside down.
The Source pin shound be connected to "ground"/0V and the Drain pin should be connected to your relay/"BRAKE_LSD_3".

Remember that most MOSFETs have a "body diode" in parallel with the Drain and Source.
If you look at the symbol of your MOSFET you'll see a little arrow in the middle - that gives you a hint as to which way the diode will allow current to flow through the MOSFET no matter whether its turned on or off.

Comment: Okay do you know why its still give me voltage change from 3.3V to 0V though

Comment: Its probably related to the fact that this isn't a simple MOSFET, but one of them new-fangled "IntelliFET" thingies and there's a current path from the 'IN' terminal to the 'S' terminal - maybe through whatever they've got in there for ESD protection.

Comment: @ynan - Turn the part around and be happy.